# webスクレイピング実行時のエラー

Tags: python, web-scraping

下記サイトを参考にwebスクレイピングをはじめて試しています。
http://blog.aidemy.net/entry/2017/12/17/214715

物は試しとAPI_KEYとCUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINEだけ取得し、画像収集のソースコードをそのまま使用させていただき実行すると下記のエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gazou_shutoku.py", line 52, in <module>
    img_list = get_image_url(keywords[j],100)
  File "gazou_shutoku.py", line 26, in get_image_url
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(query_img)
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\envs\gazou_atsume\lib\urllib\request.
py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\envs\gazou_atsume\lib\urllib\request.
py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\envs\gazou_atsume\lib\urllib\request.
py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\envs\gazou_atsume\lib\urllib\request.
py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\envs\gazou_atsume\lib\urllib\request.
py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ユーザー名\Anaconda3\envs\gazou_atsume\lib\urllib\request.
py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

何が問題なのでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージから、エラーは以下のところで発生しています。

```
res = urllib.request.urlopen(query_img)
```

それで、query_imageの内容に問題があると思われます。

```
query_img = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + API_KEY + "&cx=" + CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE + "&num=" + str(10 if(total_num-i)>10 else (total_num-i)) + "&start=" + str(i+1) + "&q=" + quote(search_item) + "&searchType=image"
```

まず、google customsearch API が有効になっているかどうかを確認ため、ブラウザーURL欄に直接以下のURLを入力してみてください。API_KEYとCUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINEのところは自分の番号を入力してください。

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE&q=生田絵梨花&searchType=image
```

それで、エラーになるようであれば、API_KEYとCUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINEの設定を再度確認してください。エラーの内容がForbiddenとなっているので恐らくその設定に問題があるものと思われます。GooleのAPIの設定をミスすることはよくあります。

それが正しく表示できるのであれば、query_imgの値をprintする等して、以下のところに `Custom Search APIs Explorer`があるので、query_imgの値が正しいかどうか確認にしてみてください。
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=ja#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list

Comment: ブラウザのURL欄に直接アドレスを入れたらipRefererBlockedとかusageLimitsとかのエラーになりました。カスタム検索とAPIキーの設定を色々と触ってみてはいるのですがエラーのままです。設定方法はこちらのサイトを参考にさせてもらっています。https://qiita.com/onlyzs/items/c56fb76ce43e45c12339

Comment: Google Cloud Platform Consoleで、customsearch API が有効になっているか、API_KEYにAPIの制限がかかっていないかも確認してみてください

Comment: Yasuhiroさんの言うとおり、APIが無効、さらに制限がかかったままでした。ありがとうございました。